# My BroadcastReceiver never gets called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

This BroadcastReceiver is inside my fragment:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),LightSensor.class));
    Log.d(TAG, "Called the LightSensor Service Class to start");

    IntentFilter luxfilter = new IntentFilter("LuxUpdate");
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mLightReceiver, luxfilter);


    ...
    }

...

    // RECEIVE DATA FROM LIGHT SENSOR BROADCAST
        public BroadcastReceiver mLightReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                String lux = intent.getStringExtra("Lux");
                Log.d(TAG, "Recieve Broadcast-Lux Update: " + lux);
                //TextView tvSensorLightLux = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSensorLightLux);
                mLightValue.setText(lux);

            }
        };
```

The problem is that I do think think that it is listening or receiving.  The Log.d never shows in the LogCat.  I have no idea why.  The only difference in this entry and another the did work, was that the previous entry was actually in an Activity.  This one is in a Fragment.  Am I missing something here or should there be something in my manifest for this fragment or receiver?

UPDATE:

THe Sensor sends the broadcast with:

```
private void sendLuxUpdate() {

        if(isLightSensing){
        Log.d(TAG, "sender Broadcasting message " + Lux);
        Intent intent = new Intent("LuxUpdate");
        intent.putExtra("Lux", Lux);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you register your receiver ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the above to reflect the reg.  In the Registration I do see the Log.d entry.  Does not mean that it was registered properly, only that it passed through that statement.

Comment: You should include also the sending of the `Intent` to the receiver, so someone may have a look if everything is fine.

Comment: It's not relevant in your code if you registered or not the receiver.

Comment: I'm still missing the register statement, it should be something like `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcast_receiver);` as you're using `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: Sorry, I added it.  Don't forget that this is a fragment

Comment: As to the not working `Log`. If you are using Android Studio check if you have `android:debuggable="true"` in your `Manifest.xml`.

Comment: The Lux  update comes from a sensor that I made into a service.  In that service is the Broadcast that should be received by the fragment so that I can update the TextViews in the fragment.  I think perhaps I have not correctly registered or something, but I have no other feedback from Eclipse

Comment: The code looks good itself, are you 100% sure you're entering the `if(isLightSensing)` statement?

Comment: In the Log Cat I have entries that show that the sensor is broadcasting. That means that the entry sendLuxUpdate() is functioning and is actually sending a value. But no response from the fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing at least 2 wrong things:

1. Register the receiver through `Context.registerReceiver()` and then you're sending broadcast updates through `LocalBroadcastmanager`. You will never get these messages. `LocalBroadcastManager` doesn't know about receivers registered through `Context` and vice-versa.
2. I don't think it's a good idea to register the receiver directly in the application context as this will leak the fragment.

So try this: register the receiver in `onCreate` or `onResume` and then unregister the same instance in the complementary method: `onDestroy` or `onPause`. Also, when registering and sending intents, use the same mechanism - either `LocalBroadcastManager`, either the `Context` based. The first one has the advantage of sending the messages only in your app.

For example, suppose your fragment is called `DeviceView`:

```
public class DeviceView extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(your_receiver, intent_filter);
        /// other code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(your_receiver);
      /// other code
    }
}
```

Comment: makes good sense.  Sounds like you are saying I am sending in one language and listening for another.  I only need to receive these braodcasts in the app.  onPause unregisters the Broadcast. Since this is a Fragment, how should I register the Receivr is I want to stick with the LocalBroadcastManager?

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())` ... just don't forget to register/unregister in complementary methods. ... and also to upvote ;)

Comment: I tried that BUT the getInstance is throwing an error saying it is not compatible with the Fragment

Comment: Can you show in what method did you try that? Also, what is the base class of your fragment?

Comment: `public class DeviceView extends Fragment {`

Comment: Where did you put `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())` ? In fragments `onCreate` maybe?

Comment: I tried both, but in both positions, the getinstance is a problem

Comment: By `both` means both `onCreate` and `onDestroy`?

Comment: The method getInstance(Context) in the type LocalBroadcastManager is not applicable for the arguments 
  (DeviceView)

Comment: The parameter to pass is `getActivity`, not current fragment

Comment: you lost me with that one, sorry